# Delete confirmation record from database in php

Tags: php, database, record

I'm making a form where you can input the record name and code so you can delete it from the database 'world'.

But I keep getting these errors :( :

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for doblok66(), called in C: on line 224 and defined in C: on line 89
>   Warning: Missing argument 2 for doblok66(), called in C: on line 224 and defined in C: on line 89
>   Notice: Undefined variable: landcode in C: on line 92
>   Notice: Undefined variable: taal in C: on line 92

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['blok66'])) {
    $taaltmp=$_POST ['taal'];
    $landtmp=$_POST ['landcode'];
    doblok66();
}
?>'

function doblok66($taal, $landcode) {
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root") ;
    $dbresultaat = mysql_select_db("world") ;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM countrylanguage  WHERE (CountryCode = '".$landcode."' AND Language = '".$taal."' ) AND IsOfficial = 'F' ";
    mysql_query($sql) ;

}
```

and the html code:

```
<h1> opdracht 6.6 </h1>

<table>
  <form action='blok6.php' method='post'>
    <tr>
      <td> taal: </td> <td> <input type="text" name="taal"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> landcode: </td> <td> <input type="text" name="landcode"></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name='blok66' value="Submit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

I just wondered whether someone could possibly take a look and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You have error messages, and that's all you need.

Comment: Please do not continue using `mysql_`-class functions. Either use `mysqli_`, `MYSQLI::`, or PDO. See http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 4):

Your function `doblok66()` expects two parameters but when you call it you give none. You need to call the function like this :

```
doblok66($taaltmp, $landtmp);
```

The problem is that you define your variables and then call a function. When PHP starts executing the function, it does not "know" the variables you defined before, you need to give these as parameters.

More info here : [PHP Functions arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) and [PHP Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)